# Site collection admin with full control does not have ManageWeb permissions?

Tags: development, permissions, site-collection, administration

I have a user set up as a **site collection admin** at the root level of my sharepoint site, and all subsites inherit these permissions. I have also verified that my user `admin1` has **FULL CONTROL** rights to the entire site...so why do 
both `IsUserAdmin` and `ManageWeb` permissions return `false`??

If I run this code against my global tenant admin user, both values return `true`. What gives? I do not believe the App-only policy applies here.

```
using (
    var ctx = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(
        webUrl, sharePointAuthResult.AccessToken))
{
    var spWeb = ctx.Web;
    var user = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(accessInfo.UserEmail);
    ctx.Load(spWeb, w => w.EffectiveBasePermissions);
    ctx.Load(user);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    var managePermission = new Permission(
        "Manage",               
        ctx.Web.EffectiveBasePermissions.Has(PermissionKind.ManageWeb));

    var isAdmin = user.IsSiteAdmin;

    /*

        managePermission.IsGranted == false    (why?)
        isAdmin                    == false    (why?)

    */
}
```

[image]

In case it's useful, I am developing an Office 365 snap-in app for Word, so I am using the OAuth2 [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/dn645542.aspx) to allow the user to grant consent to the app for read / write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

A related answer was posted here by [Vadim Gremyachev](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/10610/vadim-gremyachev). It turns out checking the `IsSiteAdmin` property on the current user object directly isn't a reliable result; instead, checking for the property on `Site.RootWeb.SiteUserInfoList` was a reliable approach for me.

[CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin should be true but returns false](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144550/currentuser-issiteadmin-should-be-true-but-returns-false)

> Another way to determine whether user is site collection administrator
>   **Supported in SharePoint 2010/2013**

```
public static bool IsUserSiteAdmin(ClientContext ctx,int userId)
{
   var userInfoList = ctx.Site.RootWeb.SiteUserInfoList;
   var item = userInfoList.GetItemById(userId);
   ctx.Load(item);
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
   return (bool)item["IsSiteAdmin"];
}
```

> Usage

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{ 
    var currentUser = ctx.Web.CurrentUser;
    ctx.Load(currentUser);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    var isCurrentUserSiteAdmin = IsUserSiteAdmin(ctx, currentUser.Id);
}
```