# Using Javascript: hide sharepoint room site content items for users except admin

Tags: javascript

I am using a code for hiding site content items for users except admin:

The below script is used to check if user is admin but `currentUser.get_isSiteAdmin()` always gives **True**:

Code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function getUserInfo()
{


    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onQuerySucceeded() 
{
  var user= currentUser.get_isSiteAdmin();
  if(user == false)
  {
    alert("user is not admin")

  }
  else
  {
  alert("user is admin")

  }

}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args)
{
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserInfo,"sp.js");

</script>
```

Comment: Please check the answer of this question - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144550/currentuser-issiteadmin-should-be-true-but-returns-false

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any user checking yourself (if you have the Admins in a SharePoint Group)

Do it the other way around.

- Hide webparts by default
- Make them visible for Admins,
  code in a CEWP **with a Target Audience** so it  only executes for the Admin-Group

This will also **not** flash/then hide contents

Comment: I want to hide list/libraries from site contents. All users have access to these libraries but they should visible to admin only. But while checking the admin it always gives every user as admin. Which is not the case.

Comment: Ah.. SiteContents is a systems page where you can't add webparts, then this method won't work.

Comment: But we can hide the 'site content' items from a normal page with content editor web part having JavaScript reference.